# How to show tooltip/value over bar chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, bar-chart

I am using *iReport 4.7 Community Edition* for making reports. And I'm using *Chrome* browser for viewing it in HTML format.

I put 3D bar chart in summary band and want to show value on its tip (i.e. on top). So I go by below way:

1) check on `show Labels` &  `show Legends` in 3D Bar Chart Properties.

2) Right click on Chart > Chart Details > Details > Category Details > by selecting category,Modify > Item Hyper link > Tool tip > Tool tip Expression > `$F{dayname(ServiceDate)}.toString()` , where `$F{dayname(ServiceDate)}` is field name

even though, its not showing anything.

Is this facility not present in community edition? Should I embed any other *.jar* file for that?

Answer (score 2):

create jar file add this line

**CategoryPlot categoryPlot = (CategoryPlot)jfreeChart.getPlot();
        categoryPlot.getRenderer().setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER));**

add this jar in ireport as customizer class